# Counting instances of a class - injecting jQuery into a third party website using Firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebug

I am accessing a third party web page with a comments section.

**The site in question:** http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/canadian-led-research-looks-to-grow-strawberries-on-mars-1.2704433

The comments section only shows a few comments and displays a "Show More" button. I am writing a script that will continue to automatically press the "Show More" button until all the comments have been displayed. Once the "Show More" button no longer displays I want to trigger a new function.

I am trying to achieve this by "injecting" my own JavaScript into the third party page through the command line in Firebug (2.0.1) in Firefox (30.0).

Using Firebug I have found that the "Show More" button's class is `vf-load-more`. I created a `setInterval()` function call and have been able to successfully "click" the button repeatedly.

Now I am trying to implement an "end of comments" recognition. I am doing this by counting the instances of `vf-load-more` on the page. If there are no instances of `vf-load-more`, start the next function.

```
numShowMore = $('.vf-load-more').length;
if (numShowMore == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval1);
    nextFunction(); //This function has not been written yet
}
```

**The problem:** `$(".vf-load-more").length;` is returning `undefined`. Why? The button **is** on the page.

**The code in it's entirety:**

```
//This injects a jQuery reference into the header
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);

//If jQuery is loaded execute the rest of the code
if (!window.jQuery)
{
  alert('jQuery is GO');

  var numShowMore;

  function clickButton()
  {
    numShowMore = $('.vf-load-more').length;
    alert('numShowMore = ' + numShowMore); //This alert returns "undefined"??
    if (numShowMore == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval1);
      nextFunction(); //This function has not been written yet
    }
    $('.vf-load-more').click();
  }

  var interval1 = setInterval(clickButton, 3000);
}
```

Now it gets weird. If I let the interval keep running and "clicking" the "Show More" button until all the comments are displayed, it will eventually stop displaying the "Show More" button. I then force the interval to stop by running `clearInterval(interval1);` in the command editor and then when I run the following code it alerts `numShowMore = 1` but the button is no longer there.

```
numShowMore = $('.vf-load-more').length;
alert('numShowMore = ' + numShowMore);
```

Why is it not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried replacing the jQuery `$` with `jQuery` and it worked. I am not sure why but I think maybe that jQuery is making a conflict with another library that is loaded on the page.

```
$('.vf-load-more').length;
```

is replaced with

```
jQuery('.vf-load-more').length;
```

and

```
$('.vf-load-more').click();
```

is replaced with

```
jQuery('.vf-load-more').click();
```

I also noticed something wrong in your code, in the if condition which checks whether jQuery is loaded or not, the condition is reversed, it shall be

```
if (window.jQuery){
//do stuff
}
```

However, because you are loading an external script which might take time to load, the condition might be false if the library is not loaded, so it's better to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to check whether jQuery is loaded or not and if it's loaded, then execute your code.

Something like this:

```
//If jQuery is loaded execute the rest of the code
var jqueryCheckTimer = setInterval(function(){
if(window.jQuery){
        clearInterval(jqueryCheckTimer);
         var interval1 = setInterval(clickButton, 3000);
    }
},100);
```

Comment: I am accepting your solution as the answer. If I change ALL instances of "$" to "jQuery" it still doesn't work so I found I have to be selective about where I make the change to make it work (for example I still have to use "$" with the .click() call or the button isn't clicked.

Comment: The main reason I selected your solution is because I also believe this is a conflicting framework issue and you have pointed me in the direction of jQuery.noConflict() which I believe will go a long way towards solving all the problems I am having. Thanks!

Comment: [Clcik here for jQuery documentation on jQuery's .noConflict() feature](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)